# Vercel is changing the contents of js file on deployment

Tags: deployment, mern, vercel

I am trying to deploy a mern app on vervel using the vercel serverless functions. The idea is that the backend will be used for serving the file present inside build folder in frontend. But, after deployment, I am constantly getting the the error:

[image]

Going to the sources, we can see the line which is causing the error:

[image]

Now, when I check the same file in my build folder, I see that there are no such lines present in the code. In fact, the code in that file in my build folder starts from line 8 of above image.
This means vercel has added the few initial lines by itself, which caused the error.

Why has it done that? And what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, I have the same problem:

hosting an express.js file on vercel and using a `<script type=module src=...></script>`

The contents of that file (located in ./assets) are loaded but changed by vercel. So instead of:

```
import { _wcl } from './common-lib.js';
import { _wccss } from './common-css.js';
```

It generates:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.MscCircleProgress = void 0;
var _commonLib = require("./common-lib.js");
var _commonCss = require("./common-css.js");
```

Which is not working in javascript modules (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)